# Use Cityhash for file integrity

Tags: c++, hash

The problem is that I want to use hash functions to check file integrity and encryption here is unnecessary, so I think the non-cryptographic hash cityhash  may be a good choice, since what I want is just the speed and less collisions.

While the [source](https://code.google.com/p/cityhash/downloads/list) has just provided the cityhash function with fixed length string as input and hash code as output. Then how can I use the function to hash a file?

Can I divide the file into several chunks, calculate every chunk's hash code and XOR every hash code? Will it affect the collision efficiency or speed? Do you have any other good ideas?

Comment: Why can't you read in the whole file and hash it as one string?  If the file is too large, than you can read the chunks and hash them all.  You can then put the results into a string, and then hash the string.  If the original algorithm is decent, then the result should be pretty uniform.

Comment: You could do it in chunks and then use the seed parameter on next chunk.

Comment: Are you only interested in file integrity in respect of "noise" or defect disk sectors? Because otherwise "no crypto hash needed" is a false assumption. Combining hash values with XOR should "work fine" for every reasonably good hash, but the result will not be the same! Your final hash will _not_ be a Cityhash hash value. As for affecting speed, you could make hashing faster by processing individual chunks in separate threads, but of course this won't work with using the seed parameter as proposed by PlasmaHH (well, it _will_ work, but sequentially).

Comment: Yes,what I want is just find out if the file has been changed as soon as possible.Use separate threads seems like a good way,I will combine it with recurrence as mentioned by Trenin to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an appropriate application for CityHash, and it will exhibit poor collision resistance when used this way.

If you want a quick file integrity checksum, use a CRC family function, like CRC16. If you want something more extensive, the speed of cryptographic hashes such as SHA1 should be more than sufficient. (Almost any modern CPU can hash data basically as fast as it can read it from memory.)

Comment: Because this is a study experiment,so I'd like to try a new algorithm instead of the traditional hash such as CRC, MD5 or SHA to see if it works:)